# Alarm Manager not cancelling pending intent in application class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I have a pending intent that does not cancel. I start the service when I login to my app and when they logout I stop it. The code below is located in my application class. Is that the proper place for it to go? I have tried to put it in the MainActivity I have but with the same results in the Application.

```
private PendingIntent mJobPendingIntent;
private final int RQSNUM_SIP = 1337;

public void startJob(){
    LogText.appendLog(TAG + " startJob");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, JobReceiver.class);
    mJobPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, RQSNUM_SIP, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    ((AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)).setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP
                                                                                        , SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+7000
                                                                                        , 7000
                                                                                        , mJobPendingIntent);
}

public void stopSipJob(){
    ((AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)).cancel(mJobPendingIntent);
    LogText.appendLog(TAG + " stopJob");
}
```

I know that stop job gets called but after I log out and call stop job, I look at my settings on the phone and see that the process is still running.

How can I stop this alarm?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create again the PendingIntent on stopSipJob()

```
public void stopSipJob(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, JobReceiver.class);
    mJobPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, RQSNUM_SIP, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    ((AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)).cancel(mJobPendingIntent);
    LogText.appendLog(TAG + " stopJob");
}
```

Comment: That did not solve the issue. When I check after the logout it is still running

Comment: Why are you using PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT? Going again through my code it's the only difference taht I see. I have sometihng like `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, RQSNUM_SIP, intent, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` from the call to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`. This is causing your problem.